# Receiving a Remote Notification in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, cloud, cloudkit

I have the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let queryNotification = CKQueryNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
    let notification = Notification(name: NSNotification.Name("Name"), object: nil, userInfo: ["Key": queryNotification])
    NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
}
```

However, I was told that this is not the right way to receive remote notifications. Instead, I was directed to use the following delegate method. I don't see how this method can be used to do what I did above. Somebody please help.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { }
```

Comment: You are correct. Remote notifications are not deliverered to the UNNotificationCenterDelegate method

Comment: @Paulw11 - With iOS 10 and higher you do have to use the `UNNotificationCenterDelegate`. `UIUserNotifications` have been deprecated.

Comment: That is true for requesting notification permissions and for processing local notifications, but you will see that `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` is *not deprecated* https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application  Also, "receive remote notifications" is not listed in the overview of `UNNotificationCenter` https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter?language=objc

Comment: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is deprecated, not `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // Extrapolate userInfo
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let queryNotification = CKQueryNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
    let notification = Notification(name: NSNotification.Name("Name"), object: nil, userInfo: ["Key": queryNotification])
    NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)

    completionHandler()
}
```